# pg_dump from Azure Postgres failing

Tags: postgresql, azure

I have an Azure Postgres flexible server running and need to take a backup of the database in it

Following the directions in 9.1.4 of The Postgres documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/backup.html#:%7E:text=To%20dump%20large%20objects%20you,that%20can%20dump%20large%20objects.)

I crafted the below pg-dump command.

```
pg_dump -b -Z0 -F t --host=hidden --username=hidden --dbname=temp --file=backup.tar
```

It runs for several hours before failing with the below output

```
pg_dump: error: error reading large object 350828: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Don't use outdated documentation. Why the "tar" format? At any rate: your problem is a different one. Dumping a database with many large objects is a problem. Make sure that the database server has enough memory (where "enough" can be very much, if you have many large objects).

Comment: What error is reported in the server log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment about 'memory' from Laurenz helped me out.
Temporarily increasing the memory and running the command helped.

[image: Screenshot on used memory stats]

Answer (score 0):

I use Azure Pg services too.
Try to use this command:

```
psql.exe -h 127.0.0.1 -U user -d database
```

This works from my side.